# Yii2 deployment on Hostgator Cpanel VPS server not working

Tags: yii2, cpanel, yii2-advanced-app

I have a domain say abcdefgh.com hosted on Hostgator Cpanel VPS Server. It has a folder inside **public_html/abcdefgh.com**.

Below are the images of deploying my yii2 website but I am unable to get the result on website.

I had previously deployed the Yii2 applications on shared hosting the same way copy pasting the folder, but here in VPS server, I am curious to know what is wrong in this?

**1. Hostgator Cpanel VPS Server Deployment**

[image]

**2. Output**

[image]

**3. Server Error Log**

```
Mon Apr 17 22:48:01.706049 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 32221] [client 117.208.9.75:49825] AH01276: 
Cannot serve directory /home/abc/public_html/abcdefgh.com/: No matching DirectoryIndex 
(index.php,index.php5,index.php4,index.php3,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.js,index.jp,index.phtml,index.shtml,index.xhtml,index.html,index.htm,index.wml,Default.html,Default.htm,default.html,default.htm,home.html,home.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

4. .htaccess file

   ```
   Options -Indexes

   # Rewrite engine
   RewriteEngine On 

   # condition with escaping special chars
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
   ```

Comment: what are you .htaccess rules ?

Comment: updated the question with .htaccess file details.

Comment: I am trying to upload my `yii2 application` but unable to do it. I have added a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66988294/6854117) can you please see it ?

Answer (score 0):

Delete this from the .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Save file and try again!

Comment: Thank you so much for reply! Bogdan,. I'll try and let you know!

Comment: Then try with Options +Indexes

Comment: Nope, Still it doesn't work. Inside chrome console it says 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)'

Comment: According to the error message: Cannot serve directory /home/abc/public_html/abcdefgh.com/ there is no folder named like that in the public_html folder. it's pretty unclear if that's an actual error or old error